# Using Postmarkdown gem but already have post model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postmark

I'm trying to add a simple blog to my existing website using the Postmarkdown gem. Unfortunately, I already have a `Post` model so postmarkdown is conflicting with that namespace

How can I tell postmarkdown to use a different name like `BlogPost` or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default route path by modifying the 'postmarkdown' line in routes.rb. For example:

```
postmarkdown :as => :blog
```

This will produce the following routes:

`http://example.com/blog                     # lists all posts
http://example.com/blog/2011                 # lists all posts from 2011
http://example.com/blog/2011/01              # lists all posts from January 2011
http://example.com/blog/2011/01/01           # lists all posts from the 1st of January 2011
http://example.com/blog/2011/01/01/test-post # show the specified post`

Comment: the issue is that Postmarkdown has models/migrations called `Post` and `Taggings` which I already have, so PostMarkdown can't run its own migrations becaues they conflict with my existing ones